# Swift: Using some vs any in init?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question regarding using the `some` vs `any` keyword in Swift. As you may see in the below code that the `init` method in `CarVersion1` uses `some` while `CarVersion2` use `any`. My question is which version is better and why?

```
protocol Engine { var typeName: String { get } }

final class ElectricEngine: Engine { var typeName: String { "Electric Engine" } }
final class PetrolEngine: Engine { var typeName: String { "Petrol Engine" } }
final class DieselEngine: Engine { var typeName: String { "Diesel Engine" } }

final class CarVersion1 {
    private var engine: any Engine
    init(engine: any Engine) { self.engine = engine }
    func printEngineType() { print(engine.typeName) }
}

final class CarVersion2 {
    private var engine: any Engine
    init(engine: some Engine) { self.engine = engine }
    func printEngineType() { print(engine.typeName) }
}

let car1 = CarVersion1(engine: ElectricEngine())
car1.printEngineType()
let car2 = CarVersion2(engine: ElectricEngine())
car2.printEngineType()
```

Answer (score 2):

The following are almost identical:

```
init(engine: some Engine) { self.engine = engine }

init<T: Engine>(engine: T) { self.engine = engine }
```

Because `some` is resolving the underlying concrete type at the compile time.

`any` on the other hand, acts very similar but unlike `some` and generic, it will **NOT** expose the actual concrete type until the runtime.

Usually, you should prefer to use `some` (compile-time) over `any` (run-time) anywhere  you can for the sake of performance, safety and reliability.

Comment: Can you add an explanation or reference **why** we should prefer to use `some` to `any`?

Comment: You should prefer compile-time logic over run-time logic for the sake of performance and safety. @soundflix

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, it doesn't particularly matter, since you immediately turn around and store it in an `any Engine`. The `any` existential box has to be constructed in either case, and so you don't get much benefit from using `some` in the `init`. (It's possibly a little worse, but I would expect it generally just doesn't matter.)

Where you would get some benefits is if you made Car generic over its Engine:

```
final class CarVersion3<E: Engine> {
    private var engine: E
    init(engine: E) { self.engine = engine }
    func printEngineType() { print(engine.typeName) }
}

let car3 = CarVersion2(engine: ElectricEngine())
car3.printEngineType()
```

This way there is no existential box required. More code can be inlined. More dispatch is static rather than dynamic. When reasonable, this is the preferred approach. The only problem is that because CarVersion3 is generic, you cannot create an Array of multiple cars with different engines. And if you need to store this in a property, it may force the containing type to also be be generic. Generics spread. That's the trade-off.

I realize in CarVersion3 there is no `some`. So, to get to your underlying question, `some` is fairly unusual in an `init` parameter. You cannot have a stored property of a `some` type, so there usually isn't a reason to pass one to `init`. The generic type is expressed on the container, not on the `init`.